# passing a final parameter to AsyncTask doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know that we should pass params to AsyncTasks in the execute(...) method.

However, I was wondering, what would happen in terms of thread safety in the following code:

```
private void foo (final CustomObj myObj) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            myObj.doSomething();

            return null;
        }

    }.execute();

}
```

Also, what does AsyncTask do with the passed params to ensure their thread safty?

Answer (score 0):

Referring [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation:

> doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread

So, exactly the same will happen in terms of thread safety to the case then you create new `Thread`, put `myObj.doSomething();` inside its `run()` and start it. Without context it's difficult to say if your call is thread-safe or not. If nothing access `myObj` other than `AsyncTask` and `myObj` itself doesn't access any common data, then I pretty sure it will be thread safe.

Regarding your second question:

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework.

And:

> AsyncTask guarantees that all callback calls are synchronized in such
>   a way that the following operations are safe without explicit
>   synchronizations.
>
> ```
> Set member fields in the constructor or onPreExecute(), and refer to them in doInBackground(Params...).
> Set member fields in doInBackground(Params...), and refer to them in onProgressUpdate(Progress...) and onPostExecute(Result).
> ```

That means that the question is not fully correct. `AsyncTask` have nothing to do with passed parameters thread safety, because it was designed for different purpose, to be just helper class for getting Thread execution results (which, based on docs will be synced in right way).

So, it's developers responsibility to ensure thread safety of passed objects inside `doInBackground()`.